# Modal plugin of Bootstrap 2 is not displayed by the center

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap modal plugin. But modal dialog is not shown in center.
Why? my mistake?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/573972/stackoverflow/bootstrap/modal.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!-- Mobile Specific-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="login" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Login to Room fuga</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      hogehoge
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
$('#login').modal();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found this workarround to fix this issue:

```
$('#YourModal').modal().css(
            {
                'margin-top': function () {
                    return -($(this).height() / 2);
                }
            })
```

Source: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/374

Comment: I removed the minus before ($this) to add a positive top margin instead of a negative margin, and that centered my dialog vertically in bootstrap 3. Using the solution directly seemed to move my dialog outside the visible area.

Comment: For my case using: 

  -($(window).height() / 2)

gave me better results

Comment: see the answer i have given just now

Answer (score 10):

if your twitter bootstrap modal dialog is not centered horizontally you can fix this via css.

just give the modal dialog a negative left margin that is half it's width like e.g. so:

```
 .modalDialogBlabla {
     margin: 0 0 0 -250px;
     width: 500px;
  }
```

Comment: Very clean and very nice solution! And although it doesn't answer the question (vertical centering), it DOES work like a charm for horizontal.

Comment: awesome. Great time saver if you're not using the defaults. Thanks nerdess!

Answer (score 10):

Capture the `show` event of the `.modal` and then calculate the new position:

```
$('body').on('show', '.modal', function(){
  $(this).css({'margin-top':($(window).height()-$(this).height())/2,'top':'0'});
});​
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sonic1980/b2EHU/**

Answer (score 2):

Based on p4810's answer above but deal with where the user is on the screen too. Works with absolute positioning.

```
$('#YourModal').modal().css(
            {
                'margin-top': function () {
                    return window.pageYOffset-($(this).height() / 2 );
                }
            });
```

Comment: Not working on IE9, Is there something IE doesn't understand about this?

Answer (score -15):

Did you try:

```
$( "#login" ).dialog({
    modal: true
});
```

Ref: http://jqueryui.com//demos/dialog/modal.html

Comment: Is this way using jquery ui?
I want to use bootstrap modal plugin. sorry.